# Why can't I assign a value to a vector as the result of a conditional statement in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have 24 .csv files, each containing hundreds of thousands of data points.

My intention is for this code to:
1. loop though each of the files in the directory
2. take a sample of 1000 random points from a single column 
3. check to see if each sample data point is below a particular level, here's where I'm stuck, if TRUE change the result[i] to 1, if FALSE then 0. The result vector doesn't change at all though. Any thoughts?

```
rm(list=ls()) 

years<-c(1990:2013)

#####################################
S=1000
level<-.075
result<-(1:S)
inBounds<-function(data){
  for(i in 1:S){
    result[i]<-(data[i] < level)
    }  
  return(mean(result))
}
#####################################

#Get sample arithmetic mean readings from 1990-2013

n=1000
temp<-data.frame()
arithMean<-data.frame()
Samp<-data.frame()
CI<-data.frame()

#Get data file names
files <- list.files(path="~/Proj",pattern="*.csv", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
for(i in 1:23){
  temp<-read.csv(files[i],header=TRUE,sep=",")
  arithMean<-temp$Arithmetic.Mean 
  Samp<-sample(arithMean,n,replace=TRUE,prob=NULL)
  CI[1,i]<-inBounds(Samp)
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?  `level` is not declared in the scope of the function.

Comment: So scope is handled differently in R, not like python or C++? level and result are created and initialized in the same block

Comment: I can't speak to those languages, but inside the function is a different block from where level and result are first created.

Comment: I see, so I would either have to declare result inside the function or pass it in, then I would be able to change it. Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The result of your entire operation is a single vector of length 23, so you can do this with `sapply`:

```
CI <- sapply(1:23, function(i) {
  temp <- read.csv(files[i], header=T, sep=",")
  return(mean(sample(temp$Arithmetic.Mean, n, replace=T, prob=NULL) < level))
})
```

The reason `result` was not changing in your function is that it was declared outside the function but you were editing it inside the function. You could move the `result<-(1:S)` inside the function to get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with scope.  The `result` vector declared after `level` is in a higher scope than the `result` vector in the function.  They are not equal.

If you want the `result` vector from the function, return it.  If you want both the vector and the average both, return a list:

```
return(list(result = result, mean = mean(result)))
```